# Processing HashMap using Java 8 Stream API

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream

I have a hash table in the form

```
Map<String, Map<String,Double>
```

I need to process it and create another one having the same structure.

Following a sample to explain the goal

```
INPUT HASH TABLE
----------------------------
|       |   12/7/2000 5.0  |
| id 1  |   13/7/2000 4.5  |
|       |   14/7/2000 3.4  |
  ...
| id N  |      ....        |

 OUTPUT HASH TABLE
|  id 1 |    1/1/1800 max(5,4.5,3.4) |
  ...             ...
```

In particular, the output must have the same keys (id1, ..., id n)
The inner hash table must have a fixed key (1/1/1800) and a processed value.

My current (not working) code:

```
output = input.entrySet()
                        .stream()
                        .collect(
                                Collectors.toMap(entry -> entry.getKey(), 
                                        entry -> Collectors.toMap(
                                                e -> "1/1/2000",
                                                e -> {
                                            // Get input array
                                            List<Object> list = entry.getValue().values().stream()
                                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

                                            DescriptiveStatistics stats = new DescriptiveStatistics();

                                            // Remove the NaN values from the input array
                                            list.forEach(v -> {
                                                if(!new Double((double)v).isNaN()) 
                                                    stats.addValue((double)v);
                                            });

                                            double value = stats.max();                         

                                            return value;
                                        }));
```

Where is the issue?

Thanks

Comment: What is the error that you're getting?

Comment: Cannot convert Map<Object,Object> to Map<String, Map<String,Double>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is trying to call `Collectors.toMap` a second type inside the first `Collectors.toMap`. `Collectors.toMap` should be passed to a method that accepts a `Collector`.

Here's one way to achieve what you want:

```
Map<String, Map<String,Double>>
output = input.entrySet()
              .stream()
              .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(),
                                        e -> Collections.singletonMap (
                                            "1/1/1800",
                                            e.getValue()
                                             .values()
                                             .stream()
                                             .filter (d->!Double.isNaN (d))
                                             .mapToDouble (Double::doubleValue)
                                             .max()
                                             .orElse(0.0))));
```

Note that there's no need for a second `Collectors.toMap`. The inner `Map`s of your output have a single entry each, so you can use `Collections.singletonMap` to create them.

Comment: And filter for !isNan.

Comment: The operation to call (max, sum, ...) should be called by reflection. So I need to perform some processing over the inner hash table. I'm using the Apache Commons Math library (see stats variable)

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Thanks. Added the filter.

Comment: @Fab Well, instead of calling `max()`, you can call `reduce()` and pass to it a `DoubleBinaryOperator` that performs the required operation.

Comment: @Eran Ok, good alternative. But, no way to fix the original code?

Comment: @Fab I'm note sure. And I don't have time to check it now.

Comment: @Fab: I’ve added a solution based on just fixing your original code, followed by improvements you can make which will eventually lead to Eran’s solution, if you follow the path entirely.

Answer (score 2):

Your original code can be solved using `Collections.singletonMap` instead of `Collectors.toMap`

```
Map<String, Map<String,Double>> output = input.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(
                        Collectors.toMap(entry -> entry.getKey(), 
                            entry -> {
                                // Get input array
                                List<Object> list = entry.getValue().values().stream()
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList());

                                DescriptiveStatistics stats = new DescriptiveStatistics();

                                // Remove the NaN values from the input array
                                list.forEach(v -> {
                                    if(!new Double((double)v).isNaN()) 
                                        stats.addValue((double)v);
                                });

                                double value = stats.max();                         

                                return Collections.singletonMap("1/1/2000", value);
                            }));
```

Or make the nested `Collectors.toMap` a part of an actual stream operation

```
Map<String, Map<String,Double>> output = input.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(entry -> entry.getKey(), 
                            entry -> Stream.of(entry.getValue()).collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                    e -> "1/1/2000",
                                    e -> {
                                // Get input array
                                List<Object> list = e.values().stream()
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList());

                                DescriptiveStatistics stats = new DescriptiveStatistics();

                                // Remove the NaN values from the input array
                                list.forEach(v -> {
                                    if(!new Double((double)v).isNaN()) 
                                        stats.addValue((double)v);
                                });

                                double value = stats.max();                         

                                return value;
                            }))));
```

though that’s quiet a baroque solution.

That said, you should be aware that there’s the standard [`DoubleSummaryStatistics`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/DoubleSummaryStatistics.html) making `DescriptiveStatistics` unnecessary, though, both are unnecessary if you only want to get the max value.

Further, `List<Object> list = e.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());` could be simplified to `List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>(e.values());` if a `List` is truly required, but here, `Collection<Double> list = e.values();` would be sufficient, and typing the collection with `Double` instead of `Object` makes the subsequent type casts unnecessary.

Using these improvements for the first variant, you’ll get

```
Map<String, Map<String,Double>> output = input.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(
                    Collectors.toMap(entry -> entry.getKey(), 
                        entry -> {
                            Collection<Double> list = entry.getValue().values();
                            DoubleSummaryStatistics stats = new DoubleSummaryStatistics();
                            list.forEach(v -> {
                                if(!Double.isNaN(v)) stats.accept(v);
                            });
                            double value = stats.getMax();                         
                            return Collections.singletonMap("1/1/2000", value);
                        }));
```

But, as said, `DoubleSummaryStatistics` still is more than needed to get the maximum:

```
Map<String, Map<String,Double>> output = input.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(entry -> entry.getKey(), 
                                      entry -> {
                                          double max = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
                                          for(double d: entry.getValue().values())
                                              if(d > max) max = d;
                                          return Collections.singletonMap("1/1/2000", max);
                                      }));
```

Note that `double` comparisons always evaluate to `false` if at least one value is `NaN`, so using the right operator, i.e. “value possibly NaN” > “current max never NaN”, we don’t need an extra conditional.

Now, you might replace the loop with a stream operation and you’ll end up at [Eran’s solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46297784/2711488). The choice is yours.